# Is there a way to throw a system error like ENOENT or EPIPE?

Tags: node.js

I want to test my process and make sure it is resilient to `EPIPE` errors, since we're seeing them in prod and they don't seem to be any problem other than missing some logging.

```js
if (process.env.TESTFAIL != null) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        throw new Error('EPIPE');
    }, 1000);
}
```

That didn't look the same though, an `EPIPE` error looks like:

```js
Error: write EPIPE at errnoException (net.js:770:11)
```

Also tried `throw new Error({code: 'EPIPE', errno: -3})` etc. but it just doesn't look the same.

Is there a way to grab the code/message out of the [Node.js objects](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_system_errors) and throw a system error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to precisely "throw" an `ENOENT`, `EPIPE`, or similar.

Simply put, they are not errors or exceptions in the JavaScript or programming language sense. They are [system error codes](http://www-numi.fnal.gov/offline_software/srt_public_context/WebDocs/Errors/unix_system_errors.html), which are integers returned (or stored) by system calls or standard library routines when certain conditions apply. (And typically on Unix or Linux systems, though other OSs have adopted the same nomenclature.)

If you want to recreate them in a meaningful way for testing, you need to create the conditions that trigger them. E.g. `ENOENT` happens when you try to open a file (path) that doesn't exist. Attempting that in your testing code can recreate the conditions under which `ENOENT` arises. You can start, then break, a pipe to get `EPIPE`. This is the only meaningful way to recreate these conditions.

It is possible to see an error at the JavaScript level that calls itself `EPIPE` say, and it's possible to throw the `EPIPE` value (32) or an `Error` that embeds either the `EPIPE` value or the string `'EPIPE'`. Those higher-level error manifestations are just outcomes of the real error condition. If you want your code to be tested against the underlying issue, you generally have to create the underlying situation.

Comment: "you generally have to create the underlying situation." got an idea of how to do that for an EPIPE? that seems to be the one that's most likely to show up out of the blue (while writing to a log etc)

Comment: Sure. Start a pipe to an external process, then while data is still transferring, kill the external process with a signal (e.g. `SIGINT` or `SIGKILL`). It's an ugly / complex thing to orchestrate compared to most unit tests, and probably falls under the heading of integration tests. But doing so is both necessary and sufficient in testing `EPIPE` handling. Utility programs like Unix `yes` (which emits an infinite sequence) can be useful externals for such tests.

Comment: Actually these errors are in node, but not exported in the public API it seems.
https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v13.3.0/lib/internal/errors.js

Answer (score 1):

You can use a workaround like

```
let err = new Error('myMessage')
err.code = 'EPIPE'
err.errno = -3
throw err;
```

or the same with a class

```
class SystemError {
 constructor(message, code, errno) {
   let err = new Error(message)
   err.code = 'EPIPE'
   err.errno = -3
   return err;
 }
}
```